# Creating Docker Bridge kills my ssh connection and my network config on Centos9

Tags: docker, networking

I'm pretty new to Docker in my Testlab i build a Virtuamachine running docker at 10.0.100.6 (centos 9) . Now i want to make a docker bridge so that the container shares the same network with my other devices.

I took this command: `docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.0.100.0/24 br0`

from the docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#specify-advanced-options

It creates a cryptical interface name with br-23123... and assignes it to the ip address 10.0.100.1 whats pretty bad because its my default gateway, crashes my network configuration and kills my ssh.
Same if i use the more specified second command:

```
docker network create \                                         
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=10.0.100.0/24 \
  --ip-range=10.0.100.0/24 \
  --gateway=10.0.100.1 \
  br0
```

Can you help me with that thx